# Unable to push checkbox values to array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Unable to print fields value. Throws **"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"** error

My component.html

```
<div class="checkbox abc-checkbox abc-checkbox-success">
 <input class="inputChk" value="Serial_Number" id="ser_num" type="checkbox" checked="true">
 <label for="Serial_Number">Serial Number</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox abc-checkbox abc-checkbox-success">
 <input class="inputChk" value="Stock_Number" id="stk_num" type="checkbox" checked="true">
 <label for="Stock_Number">Customer Stock Number</label>
</div>   
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitCheckedValues()">Submit</button>
```

My component.ts

```
export class Sample{
 fields: String[] = [];

 submitCheckedValues(){
    $('input:checkbox.inputChk').each(function ()  {
        var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");

        //printing sThisVal; 

        if(sThisVal){
            this.fields.push(sThisVal);
        }
    });
    console.log(this.fields);
}
```

Comment: First thing I'd make sure of is that "this" inside of the function is what you think it is.

Comment: $(this).val() you mean? That is the checkbox value at each iteration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this error because `this.fields` is not pointing to the `fields` property of the class. `this` refers to the scope of the anonymous function instead.

You need to save the reference in a local variable before executing the code:

```
submitCheckedValues(){
    let self = this; // Store the reference

    $('input:checkbox.inputChk').each(function ()  {
        var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");

        //printing sThisVal; 

        if(sThisVal){
            self.fields.push(sThisVal); // Use the reference of self here
        }
    });

    console.log(this.fields);
}
```

Comment: @Esco Click the checkmark to mark this question as the accepted answer if it solved your problem, it gives some extra karma to the answerer.

Comment: OK I just did. I'm new here

Answer (score 0):

I want to give another solution if you want to try

```
 $.each([1, 2, 3], (function(i, e) {
    console.log(this);
 }).bind(this));
```

You can bind each function with this after that you can access this inside each.